# Assign encrypted value into session storage

Tags: javascript, c#, session-storage

I am trying to assign the encrypted value into session storage in .cshtml file. but I couldn't. I am getting a different error each time.
Error I got:
     *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'*,
     *Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
@{
    string createApplicationRequestPKey =Request.QueryString["cpk"];
    if(createApplicationRequestPKey != null)
    {
                @:sessionStorage.setItem('CreateApplicationRequestPKey', @createApplicationRequestPKey);
                @:location.href = '/';
            }
        }</script>
```

Sample request :url?cpk=U2FsdGVkX1+S3rsDcNeHuP5g6LokgGx9/xV1QcSVR+g=

Answer (score 0):

Try using the encodeURI function in `javascript`:

```
    string createApplicationRequestPKey = encodeURI(Request.QueryString["cpk"]);
```

If you are using `c#` on the server side use base64 or urlencode:

```
    public static string Base64Encode(string plainText) {
      var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
      return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    }
    public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData) {
      var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
      return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
    }

    string encoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(cpk);
```